# How to click buttons that has sound using keyboard

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I've made a simple piano in adobe animate, its made of white and black rectangular that are buttons ,each button has a musical note when you click on it, it plays the(the audio file is set on down keyframe) note, i would like to be able to play these notes by pressing on certain keys on the keyboard, any code for that?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Hello and welcome to **StackOerflow**. As it happens, **StackOverflow** is not a free code delivery service. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly, show your efforts, your searches, the scripts you have so far and describe the problem, which is scripts working not the way you intended them to. For your problem specifically, a few simple searches like **as3 keyboard interact**, **as3 play sound**, etc., would genuinely provide you with all the scripts you need to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the help of [**Keyboard events**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html).

Each key has a key code associated with it. Example setup is below:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent) :void 
{
    trace("keyDownHandler: " + event.keyCode); //# is key-code of key pressed down

    if (event.keyCode == XXX) //# where XXX is the key-code of pressed key
    {
        //# put your code here to play the sound for that key
    }

}

function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent) :void 
{
    trace("keyUpHandler: " + event.keyCode); //# is key-code of key released
}
```